# separable diff eq question issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So a group and I from class are completely stuck on a step from this problem and I hoped to come here for maybe some direction.

> So the question starts as
>
> $\sqrt{1-y^2} dx - \sqrt{1-x^2} dy = 0 \ ; \quad   y(0)= \sqrt{3}/2, $

we separated and integrated and eventually got the equation

$y=\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)+C)$

I believe we may have taken a wrong turn as the final answer does not contain any trig at all. should we have plugged in the value earlier to find $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. While it doesn't seem so, the solution is actually algebraic since $\sin\arcsin x=x$ for values in the appropriate range. Here, the constant $C$ complicates things a little, but it's still doable.

So, set $\sin(\arcsin x +C)=\sin y,$ so that $y=\arcsin x + C.$ The goal is to express $\sin y$ as an algebraic expression in $x.$ Now since $y=\arcsin x + C,$ it follows that $x=\sin(y-C).$ Expanding gives $$x=\sin y\cos C-\cos y\sin C=a\cos y+b\sin y,$$ where I have written $a$ and $b$ for the constant factors. Thus, we have that $a\cos y=x-b\sin y.$ Recall that we're trying to solve for $\sin  y.$ If you now set $\cos y=\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}$ in the previous equation, you have a quadratic in $\sin y,$ which you may solve to find what is wanted.